# What airline academies are available to US citizens?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-training, airlines, airline-pilot

It seems that EU/Asian/Middle Eastern citizens have the opportunity to apply for several self-funded programs which (upon acceptance and completion) guarantee a job as a first officer on small twin engine aircraft flown by the sponsoring airline. Is there any such program available to US citizens? And if so, what makes an applicant competitive?

Comment: There are flight schools that do offer guaranteed jobs afterward. The flight schools will work with minor airlines and if you get 300-500 hours flight time at the school you can interview with airlines and they might offer you a job and a $11,000 tuition. This is what I plan on doing. Atp offers this https://atpflightschool.com/airline-career-pilot-program/

Comment: Are you asking if a) a US citizen can apply to those foreign programs, or b) there are similar programs in the US itself?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the Asian ones are only open to their own nationals, to give them the opportunity to become a pilot as well. Pilots are in demand, and particularly captains are hard to find. For the funding, many F/Os are now self funded, low cost airlines do usually not fund initial pilot education.

An outfit like Stella Aviation in The Netherlands did offer bank loans to fund the license, guaranteed until the student found a job.

Unfortunately, we don't see many USA citizens working as expats: they are often very expensive due to having to pay double taxes when working abroad, USA has historically had few tax agreements with other countries.

Comment: *USA has no tax agreement with any other country* https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/united-states-income-tax-treaties-a-to-z

Comment: @MJeffryes ah right a sweeping statement. I've amended the answer.

Comment: Actually the US has many double tax agreements with other countries. The issue is that they expect their citizens to keep paying US taxes even if they are living and working entirely abroad.